# Go - When iterating over map and calling a goroutine with the value as argument, the argument is always the same

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
type Connection struct {
    Conn *somepackage.Conn // does not matter what this is for this example
    Channel chan []byte
}

var connectionMap map[string]map[string]Connection

...

for connID, conn := range connectionMap["someValue"] {
    fmt.Println(connID, conn)
    go func(c *Connection) {
        fmt.Println("inside fn", connID, c)
    }(&conn)
}
```

When I run the following code the get this output:

```
6c2989b7-4e52-48b1-aa6f-60c03c4fe78a {0xc0002dc9a0 0xc0000309c0}
283560e8-2ade-431e-92e2-55751b825c67 {0xc0004f0000 0xc0004981e0}
inside fn 283560e8-2ade-431e-92e2-55751b825c67 &{0xc0004f0000 0xc0004981e0}
inside fn 283560e8-2ade-431e-92e2-55751b825c67 &{0xc0004f0000 0xc0004981e0}
```

The value that's passed to the go routines is always the last thing that I iterated over. How do I fix it?

Btw, I'm passing the `conn` as an argument to the gorountine to see if it would fix the problem but it did not because as you can see the `connID` is not passed as argument and that is also the last thing that I iterated over

Comment: `range` allocates a single `conn` variable; it reuses that variable for each iteration; i.e. in each iteration it stores the iteration's value in that same variable; hence `&conn` is always one and the same address; your goroutines, depending on _when_ they are executed, will see the value at that address that is stored in that variable at that moment, **not necessarily the one that was stored in it at the moment the goroutine was "initialized"**. To fix, do `conn := conn` at the top of the loop's body. This is a common gotcha. A change to this behaviour is scheduled from upcoming Go versions.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60078

Comment: If you want to experiment with a proposed “fix” for this common issue, see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LoopvarExperiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @[mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)
Modifying the for loop fixed it

```
for connID, conn := range connectionMap["someValue"] {
    connID := connID
    conn := conn
    go func(c *Connection) {
        fmt.Println("inside fn", connID, c)
    }(&conn)
}
```